# XSLT - How to split up a parent's children

Tags: xslt

My xml structure contains a program as the parent of both certificates and courses.  I want to split the structure up to create an independent listing of certificates and courses without the common program parent.  The original structure is:

```
<root>
  <program>
    <program-name>Math</program-name>
    <certificate>...</certificate> <!-- There can 0 or more of these -->
    <course>...</course> <!-- There can 0 or more of these -->
  </program>
  <program>
    ...
  </program>
</root>
```

The output should look like so:

```
<root>
   <program-courses>
     <program>
       <program-name>Math</program-name>
       <course/> <!-- There can 0 or more of these -->
     </program>
     ...
   </program-courses>
   <program-certificates>
     <program>
       <program-name>Math</program-name>
       <certificate/> <!-- There can 0 or more of these -->
     </program>
     ...
   </program-certificates>
</root>
```

**Update**: Answered using Paul's suggestion for using a mode this is what the relevant portion of the xslt became:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:element name="root">
            <xsl:element name="program-courses">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="root/program-area" mode="course"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="program-certificates">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="root/program-area" mode="certificate"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>           
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="program-area" mode="course">
        <xsl:element name="program-area">
           <!-- Get the name here -->
            <xsl:element name="course">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="course"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="program-area" mode="certificate">
        <xsl:element name="program-area">
           <!-- Get the name here -->
            <xsl:element name="course">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="certificate"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```

Note that this solution is pared down from the actual one so it may not work as is against the original input.

Comment: There are many potential ways to achieve this, it would help if you give us a clue as to what you have so far.

Comment: @Paul, I have nothing written so far, just a few thoughts.  What I'm thinking right now is to use a for-each on each type of child and traverse up to the parent to get the name, however that would result in repeating the program information with each child.  But if you have a suggestion or suggestions I'll consider that as an answer if I can make my own way from your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Selecting program `elements`, You could use `@mode` (on `apply-templates` and a corresponding `template`) to differentiate between whether you are operating within the output of `program-courses` or `program-certificates`
2. From `root`, you could select `program/course` or `program/certificate` to generate the output `program`.
3. From `root`, you could use `for-each select="program"` and for the part that is intended to output `program-courses` only extract the `program-name` and `course element`, and perform the corresponding extraction in the part that outputs `program-certificates`.

Comment: The use of the mode on apply-templates was what I used and this yielded a simple solution.

Comment: Actually, option 2 is the better solution - it is more robust, and potentially more performant.

Answer (score 1):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="program">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="course[1]|certificate[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="course[1]">
        <program-courses>
            <program>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="../*[not(self::certificate)]"
                                     mode="copy"/>
            </program>
        </program-courses>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="certificate[1]">
        <program-certificates>
            <program>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="../*[not(self::course)]"
                                     mode="copy"/>
            </program>
        </program-certificates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node()" mode="copy">
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<root>
    <program-certificates>
        <program>
            <program-name>Math</program-name>
            <certificate>...</certificate>
        </program>
    </program-certificates>
    <program-courses>
        <program>
            <program-name>Math</program-name>
            <course>...</course>
        </program>
    </program-courses>
</root>
```

**EDIT**: If you want something more "push style" like your posted solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node()" mode="certificate">
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node()" mode="course">
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="program">
        <program-courses>
            <program>
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="course"/>
            </program>
        </program-courses>
        <program-certificates>
            <program>
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="certificate"/>
            </program>
        </program-certificates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="course" mode="certificate"/>
    <xsl:template match="certificate" mode="course"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Sorry Alejandro, I appreciate your effort, but Paul's mode suggestion is what I ended up using.

Comment: @StevenWilkins: No problem. But do check what happens with your solution when there is no `course` or no `certificate`. Also, check my edition with a more proper "push style" solution.